# Can repeating query be saved?

Tags: python, sqlite, group-by, count, distinct

In my Python / Sqlite program, I am running queries like this

```
q=SELECT COUNT(1) FROM (SELECT a1 FROM tableX WHERE freq>=1.6 AND a3='n' AND a4='y' AND a5='q' GROUP BY a1)
q=SELECT COUNT(1) FROM (SELECT a2 FROM tableX WHERE freq>=1.6 AND a3='n' AND a4='y' AND a5='q' GROUP BY a2)
q=SELECT COUNT(1) FROM (SELECT a9 FROM tableX WHERE freq>=1.6 AND a3='n' AND a4='y' AND a5='q' GROUP BY a9)
```

So the "basic" query is the same, and the rows Sqlite gathers are the same, but because of the different grouping , I have to run the same query multiple times.

I wonder if there is a way to achieve the same output more effectively, ie. run the query only once?

Comment: What type is your q variable? Is it a string?

Comment: You can create a VIEW of the inner query and GROUP BY on the view.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In each of your subqueries, although you are using `GROUP BY`, you are not doing any aggregation, so I think that all you want is to count the distinct `aX` for each case.

You can do this in a single query and return all the counters as different columns:

```
SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT a1) AS q1,
       COUNT(DISTINCT a2) AS q2,
       COUNT(DISTINCT a9) AS q9
FROM tableX
WHERE freq >= 1.6 AND a3 = 'n' AND a4 = 'y' AND a5 = 'q';
```

Comment: Well, I am doing aggregation. The values returned for a1 are like "w", "r", "r", "w", "t" , then I group by those, and count how many different options exist.

Comment: @Wartin you are not doing any aggregation inside the subquery. COUNT() is applied after you get the results of the subquery. Each of your subqueries is equivalent to: `SELECT DISTINCT a1 FROM tableX WHERE freq>=1.6 AND a3='n' AND a4='y' AND a5='q'`, so you don't need GROUP BY.

Comment: You are right. I just tried your suggestion and it works. Thank you. I haven't yet figured out exactly how it works , but I will study it a bit more.

Answer (score 0):

If your `q` variable is a string of the query to be executed you can do what you want with loops:

```py
for i in [1, 2, 9]:
    q=f"SELECT COUNT(1) FROM (SELECT a{i} FROM tableX WHERE freq>=1.6 AND a3='n' AND a4='y' AND a5='q' GROUP BY a{i})"
```